# Responsive Typography in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

What is the way to implement responsive typography in Bootstrap 5?  In version 4 I've used media queries. So for  example a blog heading will have a set of media queries and the different set of media queries for body text.

Comment: Have a look at the v5 docs: https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rfs/

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap documentation itself says that Typography while using bootstrap is **always responsive**. So you need not worry about writing any media queries. Take a look at this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/